# Storing sparse matrix & efficient iteration

Tags: c++, matrix, iterator, sparse-matrix

What is the compact way of storing a sparse matrix that allows to iterate over each row and each column efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Dictionary_of_keys_.28DOK.29) on the subject mentions several ways to build data structures for sparse matrices, partly exploiting the actual structure of the matrix to represent. There doesn't seem to be a canonical way for representation which is suitable for all kinds of matrices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did read that article, but what I need is a little bit different. What I need from my matrix is just iteration over rows and columns. I don't need an access by index. Therefore there may be other specific way to store such matrix in the memory.

Comment: @typedef Ok I see, but what is the ultimate goal then? Will the rows and columns be indexed entry-wise?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "will be indexed entry-wise"? I didn't mention that read-only matrix that allows to iterate through row or column is enough.

Comment: @typedef Basically I was asking about clarification; please be more specific about what you mean by 'iterate over each row and each column'. I suppose that some data will be read from or written to the rows and columns.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I got it. So, I need a ReadOnlySparseMatrix class that (for example) has two methods: GetRowConstIterator(ui32 row) and GetColumnConstIterator(ui32 col). The iterators returned by those functions should have IsValid() methods and operator*. All described methods should be O(1). Of course, there is an easy solution for this: to store two usual sparse matricies, one is row-major, another one is column-major, but I think this could be optimized not to store the same data multiple times.

Comment: Are you using C++? If so, please tag the question correspondingly, it might potentially attract more people who are able to contribute.

Comment: I think the best you can get is a row-order sparse matrix, and a column-order sparse matrix whose data is an array of pointers, rather than an array of in-place data. But then of course a column query is O(nnz)